# Java Serial communication and multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, serial-port, blockingqueue

I am reading in data from an Arduino to a Java program I've built. What I would like to do with the data is graph and store it (probably in a CSV) at the same time. The graphing and storing shouldn't be too hard. What I'm worried about is doing it fast enough that I don't lose any incoming data. Hence, my question here is mainly one of design.

My current thought process: I have an event listener in main() that takes all incoming serial data and puts it in a queue. I have a thread (let's call it thread A) waiting at the other end for data. The thread will immediately send the data to another thread (B) before saving it to a file. Thread B worries about graphing the data.

But I'm curious, when thread A is pulling data from the queue what happens to all the data trying to go in from the event listener? Should I have another queue in case the first one is busy and just swap back and forth?

Also, any thoughts on what type of queue to use? Any input from someone who's experienced in this area is appreciated.

**Additional Info**: I am working on Linux (Ubuntu), but would like the program to be platform independent. I am using the JSSC library for reading Serial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use Java's **concurrent queues**, as they are thread safe. For example `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. If you don't use a concurrent queue, it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` when you try to access the queue with more than one thread.
2. The problem about how fast you are sending data can be solved by limiting how much/often you are sending over the serial-port. Though that will probably not be a problem.